How to publish mqtt message to a different region with AWS node.js lambda function
I have a lambda function that publishes mqtt message to a topic in the ca-central-1 region. I want to make it publish to ap-east-1 as well. However, I got the following exception when publishing to the ap-east-1 region.
2024-08-30T14:30:43.543Z    1f25dfc7-36da-4f01-93f4-7d1fa59112a3    INFO    Message published to ca-central-1 successfully
2024-08-30T14:30:44.619Z    1f25dfc7-36da-4f01-93f4-7d1fa59112a3    ERROR   Error publishing message: ForbiddenException: Forbidden
at Object.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:61:27)
at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:61:8)
at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12) {
code: 'ForbiddenException',
time: 2024-08-30T14:30:44.619Z,
requestId: '8b441c8a-910c-6de2-726d-13f609e4d49e',
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 18.007264415212966
}
Code:
async function fun1(){
    const regions = ["ca-central-1", "ap-east-1"];

    var params = {
      topic: "device/topic1",
      payload: JSON.stringify({ type: 0}),
      qos: 0,
    };

    for (const region of regions){
      const iotdata = new AWS.IotData({ endpoint: `https://xxx-ats.iot.${region}.amazonaws.com` });
      try {
        await iotdata.publish(params).promise();
        console.log(`Message published to ${region} successfully`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error publishing message:", error);
      }
    }
}

Execution role permission policy
{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "iot:Connect", "iot:Publish", "iot:Subscribe", "iot:Receive", "iot:GetThingShadow", "iot:UpdateThingShadow", "iot:DeleteThingShadow", "iot:ListNamedShadowsForThing" ], "Resource": "*" } ] }

I couldn't find any solution to this. So I created a lambda function in ap-east-1 that publishes mqtt messages and trigger it from ca-central-1.
